# Is it possible to access the `session` table using db_query/db_update/db_insert?

Tags: 7, database, sessions

is there a security feature that is preventing me from doing anything with `sessions`?

I'm pretty sure this is a bad idea, but I'm switching users around after login.

User A logins in using their credentials, but we switch them to be User B.

Perhaps there's a better way to do this and I don't need to directly change `sessions` at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a bad idea :)

No, there are no extra security measures in place that would stop you having access to the `sessions` table (certainly nothing that Drupal is imposing, and if your site is working then Drupal must be able to read/write to that table).

If you want to switch users programatically I can't think of a better way than how the Devel module does it:

```
function devel_switch_user($name = NULL) {
  global $user;

  if ($user->uid) {
    module_invoke_all('user_logout', $user);
  }
  if (isset($name) && $account = user_load_by_name($name)) {
    $old_uid = $user->uid;
    $user = $account;
    $user->timestamp = time() - 9999;
    if (!$old_uid) {
      // Switch from anonymous to authorized.
      drupal_session_regenerate();
    }
    $edit = array();
    user_module_invoke('login', $edit, $user);
  }
  elseif ($user->uid) {
    session_destroy();
  }
  drupal_goto();
}
```

Even if you don't have devel installed (which obviously you shouldn't on a production server anyway), just make a copy of the function in a custom module and tweak it to your needs.

Comment: thanks!

you're right, this is definitely the better option.

out of curiosity, if you happen to have a module handy, try switching the uid value in the session table.. would be curious to know if it's just me doing something wrong.

Comment: It works in as much as it logs out the current user, but just switching the uid doesn't log the replacement user back in again for me either. I guess this would be by design but I haven't looked far enough into the session code to know for sure

Comment: I had some other stuff to handle copying user objects and such, the session update was the last piece.

interesting that it worked for you.  

thanks again for your input!